# Application for Saving video file on mobile device using IBM Worklight

Tags: download, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to develop an application which show a list of video to the user.
Only clicking the Save button in the list the corresponding video file (from a URL) should be downloaded onto the device and it should be playable even if the device is not connected to the internet.
I need to implement this on both android and iphone.
Please give me suggestions on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cordova File API to download and store files (and then play them).

Review the following:

- http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File